# Dependency injection in separated files of vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using `Vue` for my project.
Everything seems to be fine at beginning because I have knowledge about `Angular` before.

Now, I'm trying to implement DI in my `Vue` application.
I created a file named `user.service.vue` :

```
<script>
    export default {
        name: '$user',
        provide: {
            getUser: function(){
                console.log('Hello world');
                console.log(this.$http);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

And I'm trying to inject the `$user` into my `App.vue` as below:

```
<script>
    import NavigationBar from './components/shared/navigation-bar';
    import UserService from './services/user.service';

    export default {
        components: {
            NavigationBar
        },
        inject: ['$user'],
        mounted(){
            console.log(this.$user);
        }
    }
</script>
```

When I run the application, one error message shows up:

**vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:587 [Vue warn]: Injection "$user" not found**

How can I inject separated service files into my `Vue` app ?

Thanks,

**Update 1**

Even having changed my `user.service.vue` to :

```
<script>
    export default {
        provide: {
            '$user': 'Hello world'
        }
    }
</script>
```

I still have the same problem.

But when I changed my `App.vue` to :

```
export default {
        components: {
            NavigationBar
        },
        provide: {
            '$user': 'From app'
        }
    }
```

And create one component which is App's child: (Call it `user-dashboard.vue` for example)

```
export default {
        name: 'user-dashboard',
        inject: ['$user'],
        data() {
            return {
                users: []
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log(this.$user);
        }
    }
```

When I run the app, I get the message: `From app` in my console.

What I'm thinking is: the `$user` service must be provided by `App.vue` to inject to its children.

But in my application, there could me many services, such as: `user.service`, `customer.service`, ... Therefore, I cannot declare everything in my App.vue. It will be hard to maintain and fix bugs.

Any solutions please ?

Comment: You declare `getUser` and inject `$user`. Just provide `user` and inject `user`. However keep in mind that your properties are not reactive. If you wish to make them reactive you will need to use `Object.define()` with `enumerable: true` and a `getter` that maps to a reactive object/property.

Comment: fyi "provide and inject are primarily provided for advanced plugin / component library use cases. It is NOT recommended to use them in generic application code."

Comment: I feel this serves more as a comment then an answer, but I've ended up with the same question, or a form thereof. I don't know if you are currently using Typescript (which I would highly advice, Class based Js is a blessing), but for my service Injection/Provide solution I am currently looking into IoC containers for Js [InversifyJs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inversify) to be precise. Sadly you need typescript for it, but for your question in general, I think what you might be looking for is the usage of an IoC container for Js.

Comment: On a final note, I would advise separating the code for a service from an actual vue component (or .vue file) by either using .js files or .ts (Typescript). Unless your service needs Html or Css, you should be fine. (if your service needs html or css, I'd suggest writing a component that gets the service injected)

Answer (score -2):

What's wrong with using the service directly in your script?

see below:

```
<script>
    import NavigationBar from './components/shared/navigation-bar';
    import UserService from './services/user.service';

    export default {
        components: {
            NavigationBar
        },
        mounted(){
            UserService.someMethod().then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
            })
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What if I change the implementation of UserService ? For example, one interface `IUserService` with 2 different implementation : `NormalUserService`, `AdvancedUserService` ?